# get cross domain response via ajax in javascript from http to https

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, https, cross-domain-policy

I need to use api of https from my http file.
both are from different domain.
I am using AJAX of JavaScript not jQuery for this particular work.

Like flash developers use

// Allow scripting from files outside this domain.

System.security.allowInsecureDomain("*");

for accessing cross domain issue.
And evrything is working in as but i need to implement in js this functionality.

thanks in advance.
.......................................................................
I have to convert flash to html5 which i have done.
Now i need to get api response from https api url from http path.
which is giving cross domain issue.
but flash developer has put his cross domain policy code in as and its working fine.
I look for the cross domain code in js but i could not find any working code.
And my whole application is in javascript.
for communicating to the api i dont want to use jquery that will use extra bandwidth.
If any solution is available in core javascript please help.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried already and make your question more specific about the problem you are having.

Comment: I have updated my question i you get something please let me know.. its urgent...